# Trouble with opening new window in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open new window in Chrome using some JavaScript:

```
var windowTask = window.open("http://localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm", "width=800, height=500, toolbar=yes, menubar=yes, scrollbars=no");
```

But, when it opens, it has no menubar and toolbar, but it has scrollbars. What am I doing wrong?

Full code is:

```
<div id="box" style="height:90%; width:100%;">
            <script>
                dtable = new webix.ui({
                container:"box",
                view:"datatable",
                columns:[
                    { id: "taskID", header: "Task ID", fillspace: true},
                    { id: "title", header: "Title", fillspace: true},
                    { id: "status", header: "Status", fillspace: true},
                    { id: "creator", header: "Creator", fillspace: true},
                    { id: "description", header: "Description", fillspace: true},
                    { id: "responsible", header: "Responsible", fillspace: true},
                    { id: "dateCreation", header: "Date creation", fillspace: true},
                    { id: "dateStart", header: "Date start", fillspace: true},
                    { id: "dateFinish", header: "Date finish", fillspace: true}
                    ],
                    url:"http://localhost/testapp/php/tasks/getTaskList.php",
                    select:"row",
                    on:{"onItemDblClick": function () {
                        var selectedRow = dtable.getSelectedItem();
                        var windowTask = window.open("http://localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm", "width=800,height=500,toolbar=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=0");
                        windowTask.onload = function(){
                            windowTask.document.getElementById("taskID").value = selectedRow.taskID;
                            windowTask.document.getElementById("title").value = selectedRow.title;
                            windowTask.document.getElementById("status").value = selectedRow.status;
                            windowTask.document.getElementById("creator").value = selectedRow.creator;
                            windowTask.document.getElementById("responsible").value = selectedRow.responsible;
                            windowTask.document.getElementById("description").value = selectedRow.description;
                            windowTask.document.getElementById("dateCreation").value = selectedRow.dateCreation;
                            windowTask.document.getElementById("dateStart").value = selectedRow.dateStart;
                            windowTask.document.getElementById("dateFinish").value = selectedRow.dateFinish;
                        }                        
                    }}
                });
            </script>
        </div>
```

In summary:

in Mozilla this code:

```
var windowTask = window.open("localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm", "width=800,height=500,toolbar=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=0");
```

works correct, but in Chrome this:

```
var windowTask = window.open("localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm", "width=800,height=500,toolbar=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=0");
```

and this:

```
var windowTask = window.open("localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm", "width=800,height=500,toolbar=true,menubar=true,scrollbars=false");
```

and this:

```
var windowTask = window.open("localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm", "width=800,height=500,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=no");
```

still gives me no menubar and toolbar, and enabled scrollbars. What is wrong?

Comment: If you need the functionality of a bonafide window, then just open it up in a new tab. This way you will have all you need. To open it up in a new tab just omit the width and height from the string.

Answer (score 2):

Per the spec, the options string should have *no* whitespace.

> A DOMString containing a comma-separated list of window features given with their corresponding values in the form "name=value". These features include options such as the window's default size and position, whether or not to include scroll bars, and so forth. There must be no whitespace in the string. See Window features below for documentation of each of the features that can be specified.

I've adjusted your line accordingly below.

```
var windowTask = window.open(
  "http://localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html",
  "taskForm",
  "width=800,height=500,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=no"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing it to `menubar=1` and `toolbar=1` or `menubar=true` and `toolbar=true`. Changing scrollbars to `scrollbars=0` will disable scrollbars. They should also not contain any whitespace.

Final code should look like this:

`window.open("http://localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html",
"taskForm",
"width=800,height=500,toolbar=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=no");`

Comment: According to the docs, either should work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Toolbar_and_chrome_features

Comment: I try it now, but result is still same. Stil no menubar and toolbar, but scrollbars is on.

Comment: Have you removed whitespaces? like @vivalldi has posted?

Comment: Yes, i use this code in result:

var windowTask = window.open("http://localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm", "width=800,height=500,toolbar=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=0");

But, in Mozilla it works totally correct, no scrollbars, menubar and toolbar is on.

Comment: is windowTask being called somewhere on a button or something? are you sure that you are calling the variable correctly.

Comment: I add full code in question description, maby it helps. I use Webix framework.

Comment: Okay well I have never heard about Webix so I can't help you further.